# How to make your keyboard trigger an event

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm working on a todo list app on flutter. I've created a button to add a task but I want to also write my code such that upon tapping on the done/go button on my keyboard, a task also gets added. I've tried using the on tapped property in the text field widget but it doesn't work. I've also read about adding a listener but not sure if it's going to do what I want. I'm currently using the text editing controller method to store the value for the task I input. I hope I get pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

use **TextFormField** and trigger task add code in **onFieldSubmitted**.

```
TextFormField(
  ....
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
  onFieldSubmitted: (value){
     addTask(value);
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use `onSubmitted` in TextField. It is called when you click `done` on keyboard

Comment: It worked perfectly. I have just one last question. In my to-do list app. I want to write code such that if the text field for typing is empty, it should not be added or considered as text. Because I'm using a text editing controller, in an if statement I simply said if the "text.IsEmpty", it should print("empty"), otherwise just add. However when I add tap on the space button for some reason it is counted as text. What am I missing please ?

Comment: We have 3 func in TextFormField: `onSaved`, `onChanged` and `validator`. I think, with your case you can use `onChanged` and`validator` together to fix it. It like : 

`
validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          //do some thing
          return "";
        } else if (!emailValidatorRegExp.hasMatch(value)) {
          //do some thing
          return "";
        }
        return null;
      },
`